# Slickgrid Sorting only parent rows

Tags: sorting, slickgrid

I have a data view which will be rendered something like below,

```
item1
  item2
  item3
item4
```

Where, item 1 and 4 are parents, is it possible to sort only these two items? will the subitems (2 and 3) come under its parent even after sorting?
Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by implementing custom onSortHandler. Here is how I'm doing it:

1. Create your sorting function

   function customOnSortHandler_1(value1, value2, sortAsc) {...}
2. When specifying column metadata on the page have an attribute added

   ..., onSortHandler:customOnSortHandler_1, ...
3. subscribe this handler to onSort event

And in you customOnSortHandler you can do aaaaanything you want :)